# Difficulties in assigning threads for function handlers of async operations in boost asio

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, boost

I knew that the thread in which runs io_service.run() is responsible of executing function handlers of an asynchronous operation, but I have problems in assigning a thread for an asynchronous operation that fires in callback function of a parent async operation. 
For example consider the bellow program:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#include <stdio.h>
#endif

#include <fstream>  // for writting to file
#include <iostream>  // for writting to file
#include <stdlib.h>  // atoi (string to integer)
#include <chrono>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>  // for multi threading
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <signal.h> //  For Interrupt Handling (Signal Handling Event)
#include <vector>


#define max_length 46
#define server_ip1 "127.0.0.1"
//#define server_ip2 "127.0.0.1"
#define server_port 4000

#define MEM_FN(x)       boost::bind(&self_type::x, shared_from_this())
#define MEM_FN1(x,y)    boost::bind(&self_type::x, shared_from_this(),y)
#define MEM_FN2(x,y,z)  boost::bind(&self_type::x, shared_from_this(),y,z)

void talk1();
using namespace boost::asio;

io_service service, service2;
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> t_start;

ip::udp::socket sock1(service);
ip::udp::endpoint ep1( ip::address::from_string(server_ip1), 4000);
//ip::udp::socket sock2(service);
//ip::udp::endpoint ep2( ip::address::from_string(server_ip2), 4000);

std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> tc;
int OnCon[2];

class talk_to_svr1 : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<talk_to_svr1>, boost::noncopyable {
    typedef talk_to_svr1 self_type;
    talk_to_svr1(const std::string & message, ip::udp::endpoint ep) : started_(true), message_(message) {}

    void start(ip::udp::endpoint ep) {
        do_write(message_);
    }
public:
    typedef boost::system::error_code error_code;
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<talk_to_svr1> ptr;

    static ptr start(ip::udp::endpoint ep, const std::string & message) {
        ptr new_(new talk_to_svr1(message, ep));
        new_->start(ep);
        return new_;
    }
    bool started() { return started_; }

private:
    void on_read(const error_code & err, size_t bytes) {
        this->t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();  // Time of finished reading
        if ( !err) {
            auto t0_rel = 1.e-9*std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t0-t_start).count();
            auto t1_rel = 1.e-9*std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t1-t_start).count();
            auto t2_rel = 1.e-9*std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2-t_start).count();
            std::cout << "Sock1: " << t0_rel << ", " << t1_rel << ", " << t2_rel << std::endl;
            std::string msg(read_buffer_, bytes);
            std::cout << msg << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Error occured in reading data from server (Sock1)" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void on_write(const error_code & err, size_t bytes) {
        this->t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();  // Time of finished writting
        std::cout << "Sock1 successfully sent " << bytes << " bytes of data" << std::endl;
        do_read();
    }

    void do_read() {
        sock1.async_receive_from(buffer(read_buffer_),ep1 ,MEM_FN2(on_read,_1,_2));

    }

    void do_write(const std::string & msg) {
        if ( !started() ) return;
        std::copy(msg.begin(), msg.end(), write_buffer_);

        this->t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();  // Time of starting to write
        sock1.async_send_to( buffer(write_buffer_, msg.size()), ep1, MEM_FN2(on_write,_1,_2) );
    }

public:
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> t0; // Time of starting to write
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> t1;  // Time of finished writting
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> t2;  // Time of finished reading

private:
    int indx;
    char read_buffer_[max_length];
    char write_buffer_[max_length];
    bool started_;
    std::string message_;
};

void wait_s(int seconds)
{
  boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds{seconds});
}

void wait_ms(int msecs) {
    boost::this_thread::sleep( boost::posix_time::millisec(msecs));
}

void async_thread() {
    service.run();
}

void async_thread2() {
    service2.run();
}
void GoOperational(int indx) {


    if (indx == 0) {

        talk_to_svr1::start(ep1, "Message01");
        wait_s(1);
        talk_to_svr1::start(ep1, "Message02");
        wait_s(2);
    } 
    else if (indx == 1) {
        //talk_to_svr2::start(ep2, "Masoud");
        wait_s(1);
        //talk_to_svr2::start(ep2, "Ahmad");
        wait_s(2);
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Wrong index!." << std::endl;
    }
}

void on_connect(const boost::system::error_code & err, int ii) {
    std::cout << "Socket "<< ii << " is connected."<< std::endl;
    OnCon[ii] = 1;
    if ( !err)      {
        tc = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto ty = 1.e-9*std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(tc-t_start).count();
        std::cout << "Sock " << ii << " connected at time: " << ty << " seconds" << std::endl; 

        if ( (OnCon[0] /*+ OnCon[1]*/ ) == 1) { 
            GoOperational(0);
            //GoOperational(1);
            }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Socket " << ii << "had a problem for connecting to server.";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    OnCon[0] = 0;
    OnCon[1] = 0;
    ep1 = ep1;
    //ep2 = ep2;
    std::cout.precision(9);
    std::cout << "///////////////////////" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Socket Number, Time of starting to write, Time of finished writting, time of finished reading" << std::endl;
    t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    sock1.async_connect(ep1, boost::bind(on_connect, boost::asio::placeholders::error, 0));
    //sock2.async_connect(ep2, boost::bind(on_connect, boost::asio::placeholders::error, 1));

    boost::thread b{boost::bind(async_thread)};
    b.join();

}
```

In this program I have a global udp socket named sock1 which will connect by running sock1.async_connect() at line #9 of main function. At the callback function of this asynchronous operation, I make two instance of talk_to_svr1 class which each of them is responsible for sending a messages to server and then receiving the response from server asynchronously. 
I need to wait 3 seconds before sending second message and that is why I called wait_s(1) before making second instance of talk_to_svr1. *The problem is that calling wait_s(1) in addition to pausing the main thread will also pause the the asynchronous sending operation which is not desired.*

I would be grateful if anybody could change the above code in a way that another thread become responsible for asynchronously sending message to server so that calling wait_s(1) will not pause sending operation.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: posted an alternative using coroutines as well

Asynchronous coding *by definition* doesn't require you to "control" threads. In fact, you shouldn't need threads. Of course, you can't block inside completion handlers because that will hinder progress.

You can simply use a timer, expiring in 3s, async_wait for it and in its completion handler send the second request.

Here's a big cleanup of your code. Note that I removed all use of global variables. They were making things very error prone and leading to a lot of duplication (in fact `talk_to_svr1` hardcoded `ep1` and `sock1` so it was useless for your second channel, that was *largely* commented out).

The crux of the change is to have `message_operation` take a continuation:

```
template <typename F_>
void async_message(udp::socket& s, std::string const& message, F_&& handler) {
    using Op = message_operation<F_>;
    boost::shared_ptr<Op> new_(new Op(s, message, std::forward<F_>(handler)));
    new_->do_write();
}
```

When the message/response is completed, `handler` is called. Now, we can implement the application protocol (basically what you tried to capture in on_connect/GoOperational):

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// basic protocol (2 messages, 1 delay)
struct ApplicationProtocol {
    ApplicationProtocol(ba::io_service& service, udp::endpoint ep, std::string m1, std::string m2, std::chrono::seconds delay = 3s)
        : _service(service),
          _endpoint(ep),
          message1(std::move(m1)), message2(std::move(m2)),
          delay(delay), timer(service)
    { }

    void go() {
        _socket.async_connect(_endpoint, boost::bind(&ApplicationProtocol::on_connect, this, _1));
    }

  private:
    ba::io_service& _service;
    udp::socket _socket{_service};
    udp::endpoint _endpoint;

    std::string message1, message2;
    std::chrono::seconds delay;
    ba::high_resolution_timer timer;

    void on_connect(error_code ec) {
        std::cout << _endpoint << " connected at " << relatime() << " ms\n";

        if (!ec) {
            async_message(_socket, message1, boost::bind(&ApplicationProtocol::on_message1_sent, this, _1, _2));
        } else {
            std::cout << "Socket had a problem for connecting to server.";
        }
    }

    void on_message1_sent(error_code ec, std::string response) {
        if (ec)
            std::cout << "Message 1 failed: " << ec.message() << "\n";
        else {
            std::cout << "Message 1 returned: '" << response << "'\n";

            timer.expires_from_now(delay);
            timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&ApplicationProtocol::on_delay_complete, this, _1));
        }
    }

    void on_delay_complete(error_code ec) {
        if (ec)
            std::cout << "Delay faile: " << ec.message() << "\n";
        else {
            std::cout << "Delay completed\n";

            async_message(_socket, message2, boost::bind(&ApplicationProtocol::on_message2_sent, this, _1, _2));
        }
    }

    void on_message2_sent(error_code ec, std::string response) {
        if (ec)
            std::cout << "Message 2 failed: " << ec.message() << "\n";
        else {
            std::cout << "Message 2 returned: '" << response << "'\n";
        }
    }
};
```

Note how much simpler it becomes to use it:

```
int main() {
    ba::io_service service;

    std::cout.precision(2);
    std::cout << std::fixed;

    ApplicationProtocol 
        channel1(service, {{}, 4000}, "Message01\n", "Message02\n", 3s),
        channel2(service, {{}, 4001}, "Masoud\n", "Ahmad\n", 2s);

    channel1.go();
    channel2.go();

    service.run();
}
```

When running two udp services like so:

```
yes first|nl|netcat -ulp 4000& yes second|nl|netcat -ulp 4001& time wait
```

We get the following output: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee2849d864d113b4)</kbd>**

```
0.0.0.0:4000 connected at 1.87 ms
0.0.0.0:4001 connected at 1.99 ms
127.0.0.1:4000 successfully sent 10 bytes of data
127.0.0.1:4001 successfully sent 7 bytes of data
127.0.0.1:4000: start 1.91, written 2.03, finished 2.25 ms
Message 1 returned: '     1 first
     2  first
     3  first
     4  '
127.0.0.1:4001: start 2.00, written 2.06, finished 2.34 ms
Message 1 returned: '     1 second
     2  second
     3  second
    '
Delay completed
127.0.0.1:4001 successfully sent 6 bytes of data
127.0.0.1:4001: start 2002.46, written 2002.49, finished 2002.53 ms
Message 2 returned: '47 second
   148  second
   149  second
   150  s'
Delay completed
127.0.0.1:4000 successfully sent 10 bytes of data
127.0.0.1:4000: start 3002.36, written 3002.39, finished 3002.41 ms
Message 2 returned: 'first
   159  first
   160  first
   161  first
 '
```

And the server side receives the following messages in sequence:

[image]

### Full Code

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee2849d864d113b4)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/high_resolution_timer.hpp>

#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

#define MEM_FN2(x, y, z) boost::bind(&self_type::x, shared_from_this(), y, z)

namespace ba = boost::asio;
using ba::ip::udp;
using boost::system::error_code;
using ba::asio_handler_invoke;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// timing stuff
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using hrclock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using time_point = hrclock::time_point;

static double relatime(time_point tp = hrclock::now()) {
    static const time_point t_start = hrclock::now();
    return (tp - t_start)/1.0ms;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// message operation - with F continuation
template <typename F>
class message_operation : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<message_operation<F> >, boost::noncopyable {
    typedef message_operation self_type;

    template <typename F_>
    friend void async_message(udp::socket&, std::string const&, F_&&);

  private:
    template <typename F_>
    message_operation(udp::socket& s, std::string message, F_&& handler)
      : _socket(s), _endpoint(s.remote_endpoint()), handler_(std::forward<F_>(handler)), message_(std::move(message)) {}

    using boost::enable_shared_from_this<message_operation>::shared_from_this;
    void do_write() {
        t0 = hrclock::now(); // Time of starting to write
        _socket.async_send_to(ba::buffer(message_), _endpoint, MEM_FN2(on_write, _1, _2));
    }

    void on_write(const error_code & err, size_t bytes) {
        t1 = hrclock::now(); // Time of finished writting
        if (err)
            handler_(err, "");
        else
        {
            std::cout << _endpoint << " successfully sent " << bytes << " bytes of data\n";
            do_read();
        }
    }

    void do_read() {
        _socket.async_receive_from(ba::buffer(read_buffer_), _sender, MEM_FN2(on_read, _1, _2));
    }

    void on_read(const error_code &err, size_t bytes) {
        t2 = hrclock::now(); // Time of finished reading

        if (!err) {
            std::cout << _endpoint 
                << ": start "    << relatime(t0)
                << ", written "  << relatime(t1)
                << ", finished " << relatime(t2)
                << " ms\n";

            handler_(err, std::string(read_buffer_, bytes));
        } else {
            std::cout << "Error occured in reading data from server\n";
        }
    }

    time_point t0, t1, t2; // Time of starting to write, finished writting, finished reading

    // params
    udp::socket& _socket;
    udp::endpoint _endpoint;
    F handler_;

    // sending
    std::string message_;

    // receiving
    udp::endpoint _sender;
    char read_buffer_[46];
};

template <typename F_>
void async_message(udp::socket& s, std::string const& message, F_&& handler) {
    using Op = message_operation<F_>;
    boost::shared_ptr<Op> new_(new Op(s, message, std::forward<F_>(handler)));
    new_->do_write();
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// basic protocol (2 messages, 1 delay)
struct ApplicationProtocol {
    ApplicationProtocol(ba::io_service& service, udp::endpoint ep, std::string m1, std::string m2, std::chrono::seconds delay = 3s)
        : _service(service),
          _endpoint(ep),
          message1(std::move(m1)), message2(std::move(m2)),
          delay(delay), timer(service)
    { }

    void go() {
        _socket.async_connect(_endpoint, boost::bind(&ApplicationProtocol::on_connect, this, _1));
    }

  private:
    ba::io_service& _service;
    udp::socket _socket{_service};
    udp::endpoint _endpoint;

    std::string message1, message2;
    std::chrono::seconds delay;
    ba::high_resolution_timer timer;

    void on_connect(error_code ec) {
        std::cout << _endpoint << " connected at " << relatime() << " ms\n";

        if (!ec) {
            async_message(_socket, message1, boost::bind(&ApplicationProtocol::on_message1_sent, this, _1, _2));
        } else {
            std::cout << "Socket had a problem for connecting to server.";
        }
    }

    void on_message1_sent(error_code ec, std::string response) {
        if (ec)
            std::cout << "Message 1 failed: " << ec.message() << "\n";
        else {
            std::cout << "Message 1 returned: '" << response << "'\n";

            timer.expires_from_now(delay);
            timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&ApplicationProtocol::on_delay_complete, this, _1));
        }
    }

    void on_delay_complete(error_code ec) {
        if (ec)
            std::cout << "Delay faile: " << ec.message() << "\n";
        else {
            std::cout << "Delay completed\n";

            async_message(_socket, message2, boost::bind(&ApplicationProtocol::on_message2_sent, this, _1, _2));
        }
    }

    void on_message2_sent(error_code ec, std::string response) {
        if (ec)
            std::cout << "Message 2 failed: " << ec.message() << "\n";
        else {
            std::cout << "Message 2 returned: '" << response << "'\n";
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    ba::io_service service;
    relatime(); // start the clock

    std::cout.precision(2);
    std::cout << std::fixed;

    ApplicationProtocol 
        channel1(service, {{}, 4000}, "Message01\n", "Message02\n", 3s),
        channel2(service, {{}, 4001}, "Masoud\n", "Ahmad\n", 2s);

    channel1.go();
    channel2.go();

    service.run();
}
```

Comment: Posted an alternative in [70 LoC instead of 180 LoC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46498774/85371) using coroutines

Comment: Thanks for your complete response. I did my best to realize your code but cause I am beginner in Boost & C++ programming I could not fully understand it and hence I was unable to use it for my final program. I am going to describe what I want to do in my final program in a new answer and I would be grateful if you could help me for that.

Comment: Consider we have 14 udp server at IP ranges starting from 192.168.1.101 to 192.168.1.114 all listening on port 4000. All of these servers have similar manners for responding the clients. Each server has a counter sets to 0 at start. After receiving first message the server send back the value of its counter to client program. Every 1 ms the server adds one unit to this counter and send back its new value to client in an infinite loop.

Comment: Sending new messages to server would just reset its counter to zero. I am trying to write a program to send 14 different messages to these servers simultaneously. To explain the the word simultaneously lets assume that each of these 14 messages starts to write at time t_i (i = 1, 2, 3, ..., 14). I need a client program to send all of these messages in a way that (max(t_i) - min(t_i)) < 0.7 ms.

Comment: After sending first series of 14 messages the client should start receive all the returned messages from each server which will publish every 1 ms. Concurrently after passing 10 ms (pause 10ms) the client should send second series of 14 messages and pause 10 ms to send third series of messages simultaneously and repeat this pattern for 10 times.

please note that while pausing between sending two series of message, the client should continuously receives all the returned messages from servers.

Any help for writing such a server and client program is greatly appreciated.

Comment: ... Firstly, I can still read your deleted "answer" (I'm >10k rep) and please, SO is not "hire a programmer"

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the ["normal" answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46498341/85371) posted before, here's one that does exactly the same but using coroutines:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/767f96e8479d9ca2)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/high_resolution_timer.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace ba = boost::asio;
using ba::ip::udp;
using boost::system::error_code;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// timing stuff
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using hrclock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using time_point = hrclock::time_point;

static double relatime(time_point tp = hrclock::now()) {
    static const time_point t_start = hrclock::now();
    return (tp - t_start)/1.0ms;
}

int main() {
    ba::io_service service;
    relatime(); // start the clock

    std::cout.precision(2);
    std::cout << std::fixed;

    auto go = [&](udp::endpoint ep, std::string const& m1, std::string const& m2, hrclock::duration delay) {
        ba::spawn(service, [=,&service](ba::yield_context yield) {
            udp::socket sock(service);
            time_point t0, t1, t2;

            auto async_message = [&](std::string const& message) {
                t0 = hrclock::now();

                auto bytes = sock.async_send_to(ba::buffer(message), ep, yield);
                t1 = hrclock::now();

                char read_buffer_[46];
                udp::endpoint _sender;
                bytes = sock.async_receive_from(ba::buffer(read_buffer_), _sender, yield);
                t2 = hrclock::now();

                return std::string {read_buffer_, bytes};
            };

            try {
                sock.async_connect(ep, yield);
                std::cout << ep << " connected at " << relatime() << " ms\n";

                std::cout << "Message 1 returned: '" << async_message(m1) << "'\n";
                std::cout << ep << ": start "    << relatime(t0) << ", written "  << relatime(t1) << ", finished " << relatime(t2) << " ms\n";
                ba::high_resolution_timer timer(service, delay);
                timer.async_wait(yield);

                std::cout << "Message 2 returned: '" << async_message(m2) << "'\n";
                std::cout << ep << ": start "    << relatime(t0) << ", written "  << relatime(t1) << ", finished " << relatime(t2) << " ms\n";
            } catch(std::exception const& e) {
                std::cout << ep << " error: " << e.what() << "\n";
            }
        });
    };

    go({{}, 4000}, "Message01\n", "Message02\n", 3s),
    go({{}, 4001}, "Masoud\n", "Ahmad\n", 2s);

    service.run();
}
```

As you can see, using coroutines has the luxury of having all coro state "implicitly" on the coro stack. This means: no more adhoc classes for async operations with state, and vastly reduced lifetime issues.

Output

```
0.0.0.0:4000 connected at 0.52 ms
Message 1 returned: '0.0.0.0:4001 connected at 0.64 ms
Message 1 returned: '     1 first
     2  first
     3  first
     4  '
0.0.0.0:4000: start 0.55, written 0.68, finished 0.86 ms
     1  second
     2  second
     3  second
    '
0.0.0.0:4001: start 0.65, written 0.70, finished 0.91 ms
Message 2 returned: '47 second
   148  second
   149  second
   150  s'
0.0.0.0:4001: start 2001.03, written 2001.06, finished 2001.07 ms
Message 2 returned: 'first
   159  first
   160  first
   161  first
 '
0.0.0.0:4000: start 3001.10, written 3001.15, finished 3001.16 ms
```

Comment: For absolute fun and giggles, [start here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41eafe20f4a2cd23), if you run it outside of coliru, will print something like this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25682612/, the send time windows: https://i.imgur.com/jZAfGxJ.png

Comment: In short, it doesn't look like it's easy to get the windows <0.7ms on regular hardware. For better statistics, look at [this run](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25682710/) of 100 scheduled pings, graphed: https://i.imgur.com/oOSzaIg.png. The mean window is 0.299ms, stdev 0.36ms. Likely, this would be fine for your purposes.